# tengo el siguiente error : [Error] request for member 'calificaciones' in 'dato', which is of non-class type 'Alumno()'

Tags: c++, clase, método

Aqui esta mi clase creada:

```
    class Alumno{
private://Atributos
    string nomb, sem, mat1, mat2, mat3;;
    float cal1, cal2, cal3, total;
public://Metodos
    Alumno(string, string, string, string, string, float, float, float, float);
    void materia();
    void calificacion();
    void nombre();
    void semestre();
    void promedio();
    void calificaciones();
    };
```

y aqui esta mi clase main donde me da el error:

```
    int main(){

Alumno dato();
dato.calificaciones;  //aqui me remarca que es el error
```

el error es este [Error] request for member 'calificaciones' in 'dato', which is of non-class type 'Alumno()'.

quien pueda ayudarme lo agradeceria
Gracias!

Comment: Si lo colocas asi, lo tratascomo una variable. Te faltan los ()

Comment: Y te sobran los `( )` en la línea anterior.

Comment: @Juanjo ya los eh quitado pero ahora surge otro error                                       
 [Error] no matching function for call to 'Alumno::Alumno()'

Comment: Por favor, busca el curso de introducción a C++ mas básico que exista en la red y échale un vistazo. Tu clase **no tiene** definido un constructor sin argumentos, así que el compilador se queja. Tu único constructor necesita 9 argumentos.

Answer (score 0):

Tu error puede ser reproducido con este código:

```
class C
{
    void f(){};
};

int main()
{
    C c();
    c.f(); // <--- Error
    return 0
}
```

Lo que sucede es que el compilador ha confundido la definición `C c()` por una función llamada `c` que devuelve un valor  de tipo `C` y no recibe parámetros. Por lo tanto, tu definición:

```
Alumno dato();
```

Está siendo confundida por una función llamada `dato` que devuelve un valor de tipo `Alumno` y no recibe parámetros. Para solucionarlo tienes las siguientes opciones:

- El constructor por defecto, se llama sin necesidad de paréntesis, elimínalos:

  ```
   Alumno dato; // No necesita los paréntesis '()'
   dato.calificaciones();
  ```
- Puedes cambiar los paréntesis por llaves:

  ```
   Alumno dato{}; // Llama al constructor por defecto.
   dato.calificaciones();
  ```

Comment: eh cambiado lo de los parentesis y ahora me surge otro error en la linea de arriba                                                                                                                                                                                             [Error] no matching function for call to 'Alumno::Alumno()'

Comment: Ell error te dice que no hay un constructor de `Alumno` que no acepte parámetros. Si un objeto tiene un constructor personalizado, el constructor por defecto no se genera.